# Path crystal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want that my crystal report, if the project is moved to another folder, keeps working without changing the code. Thats the code right now in my WinForm

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        string reportPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "CrystalReport1.rpt");
        cryRpt.Load(reportPath);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

[image: Error]

It means : Operation not supported. Can not open a document prepared by the JRC engine stack C + +

Comment: That code isnt working, I get an error that the report isnt loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the rpt file is present?

Looks like error is refering to other problem, not the file location.

Try this, in order to test if file location is the problem or not:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();

        string rpt = "CrystalReport1.rpt";
        string reportFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string reportPath = Path.Combine(reportFolder, rpt);

        if(!File.Exists(reportPath))
        {
             MessageBox.Show("File " + rpt + " not found in " + reportFolder );
             return;
        }
        cryRpt.Load(reportPath);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Comment: I get an error for the MessageBox code.. it says that its Type but its used as Variable

Comment: Alright, it says File not found, still the file is in the folder of the project

Comment: `string reportPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);` like that?

Comment: Thats code isnt finding my file, just the folder, how do I get the file too?

Comment: I got it working anyway :) the code is correct so your answer is correct too, the problem was the PC